# What is Spring beans what is the usage of beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I am beginner in Spring MVC and a question that I have is why the beans are used.

As I got to know beans only have private variables with getters and setters.

I have few questions,

> is that the same beans appear in Spring MVC,
>
> why beans are used in Spring what is the syntax for defining beans
>
> (my project is sampleSpr) sampleSpr-servlet.xml (which is in WEB-INF)

can someone help me to solve these questions please.

Answer (score 3):

> The objects that form the backbone of your application and that are
>   managed by the Spring IoC container are called beans. A bean is an
>   object that is instantiated, assembled, and otherwise managed by a
>   Spring IoC container. These beans are created with the configuration
>   metadata that you supply to the container, for example, in the form of
>   XML  definitions.

More to learn about beans and scope from [SpringSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html):

> When you create a bean definition what you are actually creating is a
>   recipe for creating actual instances of the class defined by that bean
>   definition. The idea that a bean definition is a recipe is important,
>   because it means that, just like a class, you can potentially have
>   many object instances created from a single recipe.
>
> You can control not only the various dependencies and configuration
>   values that are to be plugged into an object that is created from a
>   particular bean definition, but also the scope of the objects created
>   from a particular bean definition. This approach is very powerful and
>   gives you the flexibility to choose the scope of the objects you
>   create through configuration instead of having to 'bake in' the scope
>   of an object at the Java class level. Beans can be defined to be
>   deployed in one of a number of scopes

`beans` is the namespace prefix for the Spring beans [XML schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html). The mapping of namespace prefix to namespace in schema definition is done elsewhere--most likely in the root element.

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

no prefix is necessary because the *default* namespace is mapped to the same schema--again, most likely in the root element. From the documentation:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

The `xmlns:` means the default namespace is *http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans*. In the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute, you see the namespace is mapped to the Spring beans schema where that namespace is defined:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
```